# Get absolute current date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, time-format

I want to get the current date in the UTC - 7 timezone.

Every method I tried starts with a local date, and I want that any user from any timezone gets the same date.

Comment: Use `new Date().toUTCString()` which will give the time in UTC format irrespective of timezone. Also, If the users are in different timezones then the dates could be different in different locations.

Comment: Thank you @Nithish, what I'm looking for is a way so that users would get always the same date no matter their location. Also, that method returns a string, I would like to obtain a date so I can substract the 7 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a library such as [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) for this purpose, this will handle Daylight Saving Time changes properly as well.

You can also use Date.toLocaleString() to get the formatted time in a given timezone

```js
function getTimeInTimezone(timezone) {
    return moment.tz(timezone);
}

/* Using moment timezone */
let m = getTimeInTimezone("Etc/GMT+7");
console.log("Time in UTC-7 (moment):", m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));

let d = new Date();
console.log("Time in UTC-7 (toLocaleString):",  d.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: "Etc/GMT+7" }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```